# « n'avoir qu'à » : « être de votre/ta/etc. faute, sans » ou « il vous/te/etc. suffire de » ?

Tags: sens

Dans les phrases suivantes il faut comprendre « c'est de sa faute, sans ».

> Il est arrivé seulement dix minutes après l'heure et ils lui ont refusé l'entrée, comme je l'en avais averti; je n'y suis pour rien s'il n'a pas été accepté, *il n'a qu'à* se présenter à l'heure!

(*c'est de sa faute, sans* se présenter à l'heure.)

Dans ce nouveau paragraphe il faut comprendre « il vous suffit de »;

> Il y a quelques formalités, des papiers faciles à remplir; une fois cela fait *vous n'avez qu'à* attendre une semaine ou deux et vous avez votre autorisation.

(*il vous suffit d'* attendre une semaine ou deux)

La question est celle-ci; y a-t-il un principe assez concis et général qui permette à l'utilisateur du langage sans encore trop d'expérience de décider de quelle interprétation<sup>1</sup> il s'agit?

<sup>1</sup><sub>Les formes « *être de votre/ta etc. faute, sans* » et « *suffire de* »  représentent un certain nombre d'autres possibilités que l'on peut substituer pour ainsi dire quelque chose de similaire mais toujours général et négatif; par exemple, au lieu de « être votre/ta faute, sans » le message à la personne en faute peut être de la sorte suivante: « c'est tant pis pour vous/toi ». Les traductions vers une langue étrangère devraient d'ailleurs être faites selon ces possibilités variées de substitution.</sub>

Comment: Dans la première phrase, le présent détonne. Je conclurais plutôt la phrase par *il n'avait qu'à se présenter à l'heure* puisqu'on parle d'un fait passé ou alors *il n'a qu'à se présenter à l'heure la prochaine fois !*

Comment: @jlliagre Je sais que votre possibilité est tout à fait acceptable, mais c'est une affaire de ce que veut communiquer le locuteur; dans votre cas le jugement est porté sur cette seule occurrence d'arrivée en retard  dont il est question dans ce qui précède; néanmoins, le locuteur peut vouloir généraliser, et dire « Quelles que soit les circonstances il n'a qu'à se présenter à l' heure!»; la phrase dans mon texte a l'équivalent de « il n'a qu'à avoir l'habitude de se présenter à l'heure! ». On exprime les habitudes au moyen du présent : « Il se lève à sept heures.. », « Il parle peu », etc.

Comment: @Montéedelait Voudriez-vous restituer votre réponse, de façon à que je puisse en prendre connaissance; il se trouve que je ne l'avais même pas lue. Dites-vous bien aussi que je ne suis pas le seul juge en la matière d'évaluer le bien fondé d'une réponse et que si un de vos apports à une valeur certaine il y a un grand nombre d'opportunités pour récolter des votes supplémentaires dans les temps à venir, lesquels votes en fin de compte peuvent peser beaucoup plus que mon maigre « +1 ».

Comment: @Montéedelait Ceci pourrait vous intéresser : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eu+amplement+de+temps%2Ceu+amplement+le+temps&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceu%20amplement%20le%20temps%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

En fait, les deux peuvent être compris comme *il vous/lui suffit de...*. Pour le premier, il s'agit de : *pour que ça ne soit pas de sa faute, il lui suffit de se présenter à l'heure*. Le contexte est important en déterminant le but impliqué du voix imparti par une phrase, et si ce but est explicite (comme le second cas) ou implicite (comme le premier).

Comment: Il existe peut être une possibilité de rendre légitime un équivalent avec « suffire », c'est à considérer, bien que cela me semble exiger un contexte rare. Si je ne conserve pas votre «pour que…faute » qui ne convient pas (raison difficile à expliquer) mais que je remplace par « pour qu'il soit accepté » (revient à la même chose en ce qui concerne l'introduction de « suffire ») je conçois votre point de vue comme acceptable et même comme la révélation d'une ambiguïté dans le langage, mais seulement à condition que la virgule soit remplacé par des points de suspension; la virgule lie.

Comment: Je partage votre sentiment de l'inconvenance de l'usage *pour que...faute* (c'est lourd aussi en anglais, par exemple, où ça devient *so that it not be his fault*, en utilisant le subjonctif anglais); je le regarde comme forme grammaticalement pédagogique mais pas adaptée pour la langue parlée. Sur la virgule, signifiez-vous que la phrase doit devenir *pour qu'il soit accepté ... il lui suffit de se présenter à l'heure* ? Y a-t-il une grande différence de sens entre ces deux formes ?

Comment: Non, je veux dire que je conçois difficile si pas impossible, que l'on puisse choisir "suffire" et que ce qui s'impose vraiment c'est l'autre possibilité; cela repose évidemment sur une interprétation assez stricte du rôle de la virgule, qui n'introduit qu'une légère pause (au contraire des points de suspension) et que l'on utilise au lieu d'une marque de ponctuation plus forte pour montrer qu'il y a un lien entre ce qui a été dit avant et après. Évidemment, il y a une grande différence puisque l'une sert à formuler un reproche alors que l'autre sert pour une recommandation.

Comment: J’adhère à la formule avec suffire, bien que d'autres solutions sont possibles. Si vous voulez, "il n'a qu'à" peut être remplacé par "il doit/devrait/suffit/suffirait"; sauf que cette manière de parler dénigre le travail à effectuer "Il n'a qu'à remplacer le titre du PowerPoint" ou la solution du problème "vous n'avez qu'à attendre".